# Parsing string timestamp with time zone in 3-digit format followed by 'Z'

Tags: timezone, timestamp, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

In the Hadoop infrastructure (Java-based) I am getting timestamps as string values in this format:

```
2015-10-01T04:22:38:208Z
2015-10-01T04:23:35:471Z
2015-10-01T04:24:33:422Z
```

I tried different patters following [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for SimpleDateFormat Java class without any success.

Replaced 'T' with ' ' and 'Z' with '', then

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ZZZ"
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:zzz"
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:Z"
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:z"
```

Without replacement,

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:zzz'Z'"
```

In fact, this format is not listed among examples. What should I do with it?
Maybe those 3 digits are milliseconds, and time is in UTC, like this: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"? But it still should look like "2015-11-27T10:50:44.000-08:00" as standardized format ISO-8601.

Maybe, this format is not parsed correctly in the first place?

I use Ruby, Python, Pig, Hive to work with it (but not Java directly), so any example helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *very* strongly suspect the final three digits are nothing to do with time zones, but are instead milliseconds, and yes, the `Z` means UTC. It's a little odd that they're using `:` instead of `.` as the separator between seconds and milliseconds, but that can happen sometimes.

In that case you want

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSX"
```

... or use

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS'Z'"
```

and set your `SimpleDateFormat`'s time zone to UTC explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, Jon, very much appreciate your prompt reply. Anybody else shares Jon's opinion?

Comment: Yes, I agree with Jon.  It is certainly not a time zone.  Milliseconds is most likely.  `:` is wrong, it should be `.` or `,` by the ISO8601 spec.